# copying multiple files by filename

Tags: file-copy

I need to copy 150 file from a directory containing 900 files. I have the name of all 150 files in a text file, `list.txt`. How can I do this in Linux?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this with `rsync`

```
rsync -av --files-from=list_of_filenames.txt SOURCE_DIR DESTINATION_DIR/
```

notice the trailing space on the destination dir. `rsync` works from your current working directory so the file paths in your file list must be relative to that.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the file and copy:

```
while read file; do cp "$file" /path/to/target/dir; done < list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If list with your file paths are already escaped, you can use the following command:

```
cp -v $(<list.txt) dest/
```

If your list is too long, then use a [`while` solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332178/21471) as suggested in other answer.

Answer (score -1):

I will do like this:

```
for f in `cat filenames.txt`; do cp $f destination; done
```

Where you replace `destination` with the destination for you files. Often I insert a `echo` after the `do` to verify my command is correct by making a dry run.

Comment: This will fail if any of the file names contain whitespace. You could fix that by quoting the `$f`, but then it would still fail for file names with newlines (although, admittedly, that won't be an issue if the file names are in a list). As a general rule, never use a `for` loop to iterate over things like this. This is [bash pitfall number 1.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)